# Функция осветления цвета

Tags: php

Может кто встречал готовую?

Например, даем на вход 006a44, получаем 00ce44.

Т.е тот же цвет, только более светлый...  Теоретически нет ничего сложного, цвет переводим в 10-ричный, и увеличиваем середину (G) например, на 100, если она и так максимум 255 или больше 200, то увеличиваем первые(R).

Но у меня больше проблемы с переводом их 16 в 10-ричную систему.

```
function lighter($color)
{
    $x1 = dechex($color[0] . $color[1]);
    $x2 = dechex($color[2] . $color[3]);
    $x3 = dechex($color[4] . $color[5]);
    if ($x2 > 220) { // некуда осветлять
        if ($x1 + 150 > 255) {
            $x1 = 255;
        } else {
            $x1 = $x1 + 100;
        }
    } else {
        $x2 = $x2 + 100;
    }
    return hexdec($x1) . hexdec($x2) . hexdec($x3);
}
```

Но он не всегда верно переводит в 10 или в 16, т.к. иногда проскакивают 3-х значные значения и итоговый цвет состоит из 7 символов.

Comment: Проверяйте входной параметр и дописывайте его до 6-ти знаков, при необходимости.  
if (strlen($color)==3)
  $color=$color[0].$color[0].$color[1].$color[1].$color[2].$color[2];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш алгоритм *не совсем верен*. Общая идея подобных преобразований лежит в том, что надо работать с цветом в цветовом пространстве [HSL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL) - цвет представлен Цветовым тоном, Насыщенностью и [Светлотой](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%28%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%29). Вот увеличивая или уменьшая параметр Светлота можно манипулировать яркостью цвета. Поэтому необходимо перевести цвет в HSL, сделать ярче, а потом обратно в RGB.

Вот тут есть много кода с подобными манипуляциями [в ту или в другую сторону](http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/color-conversion/color-conversion/Color.php).

Также есть такой замечательный язык построения таблиц стилей как [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/). В нём есть встроенные функции осветления/затемнения/преобразования цветов. Исходная реализация SASS/SCSS выполнена на Руби, однако есть и порт на PHP - [PHamlP](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/). В исходниках можно найти реализацию данной функции - см. [SassScriptFunctions.php](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/source/browse/trunk/sass/script/SassScriptFunctions.php) и [SassColour.php](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/source/browse/trunk/sass/script/literals/SassColour.php). Цвет в этом случае можно задавать в любом виде CSS - `"#bc8f8f"`, `"#ba2"`, `"rosybrown"`, `"rgb(100%,0%,0%)"`

Comment: Если вопрос ещё актуален :-)